# How do you create a variable from hook_preprocess_page() that will be available to a node template?

Tags: 7, hooks, theming

I have this in my module "spot":

```
function spot_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $vars['social'] = 'hi';
}
```

Other things I set in this function come through fine. But my node--spot.tpl.php template is complaining that the variable does not exist:

> Notice: Undefined variable: social

I have cleared the cache.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do you create a variable from hook_preprocess_page() that will be available to a node template?

You cannot.
The parameter passed to `hook_preprocess_page()` (what you define as `&$vars`) is not the same parameter passed to `hook_preprocess_node()`, which means that if you set `$vars['social']` in the first, it is not passed to the latter. If you need to pass a value to the node template file, you need to set it in `hook_preprocess_node()`, or `hook_process_node()`.

Answer (score 1):

That hook is for page.tpl.php.  Put your code in a `hook_preprocess_node()`.